# Pearson correlation of two 3D arrays with NaN in python

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, correlation, python-xarray

I have two three-dimensional arrays a and b with [time,lat,lon]. I want to correlate the time series of each grid cell like `correlate(a[:,0,0],b[:,0,0])`, `correlate(a[:,0,1],b[:,0,1])`, ... . I'm aiming for two correlations. One with the entire time series and one only where array a surpasses a certain threshold.
The datasets also include some missing values in the time series and I read in both datasets with Xarray. Correlations and masking are done using numpy.
At the moment I walk through each latitude and longitude, grabbing the time series, mask it to account for nan and the threshold and correlate them. My code looks like this:

```
def correlate(A, B, var1, var2, TH):

   name = "corr_"+var1+"_"+var2+"_TH_"+str(TH)+".nc"
   a = xr.open_dataset(A).sel(time=slice('1950-03','2013-12'))
   b = xr.open_dataset(B).sel(time=slice('1950-03','2013-12'))

   corr = np.empty([a[var1].shape[1],a[var1].shape[2]],dtype=float)
   corr_TH = corr
   varname_TH = "r_TH_"+str(TH)

   for lt in range(corr.shape[0]):
      for ln in range(corr.shape[1]):
         corr[lt,ln]         = np.ma.corrcoef(a[var1][:,lt,ln],b[var2][:,lt,ln], rowvar=True)[0,1]
         corr_TH[lt,ln] = np.ma.corrcoef(np.ma.masked_greater(a[var1][:,lt,ln],TH),b[var2][:,lt,ln], rowvar=True)[0,1]

   # save whole correlations
   ds = xr.Dataset({'r': (['lat', 'lon'],  corr),varname_TH: (['lat', 'lon'], corr_TH)},coords={'lon': a['lon'],'lat': a['lat']})

   return ds
```

This works in general but is super slow. I found the Xarray function array.stack() to flatten the arrays and tried something like:

```
A_stack = A.var1.stack(z=('lat','lon'))
B_stack = B.var2.stack(z=('lat','lon'))

cov = ((A_stack - A_stack.mean(axis=0))* (B_stack - B_stack.mean(axis=0))).mean(axis=0)
corr = cov  / (A_stack.std(axis=0) * B_stack.std(axis=0))
```

The multi index 'z' over which the array is stacked is retained through the process, however, the correlation array in the end is empty. I suppose that's because of the Nans.

Does anyone have an idea of the do this?

thanks

Comment: maybe the example at end of this page can be helpful? http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html